# make text in form box disappear on click in webplus X5

Tags: forms

In WebPlus, I am trying to make the text in a form for a support page disappear on click, or disappear when the box has contents inserted. How could I do this?
HTML CODE at [here](https://paste.ee/p/2hEI6).

Comment: I'm not familiar with webplus, is that .NET? You have webforms tagged for your question

Comment: @PeonProgrammer Do I? whoops, wrong tag. suggestions?

Comment: Do you have experience with looking at the source HTML? I am not familiar with webplus but I assume you will need to add some javascript to your form page to hide the textbox(es) you're referring to.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer not much, but webplus could let me look at (and edit) the raw html, and some pointers on what to do would be nice. I'll upload the raw html in a second.

Comment: @PeonProgrammer added html code, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with WebPlus, it's just HTML at the end of the day.

First we need to add an ID to your Submit Button ( assume this is the button you want to click that will hide stuff?)

```
<input id="Submit" type="submit" style="position:absolute; left:137px; top:668px; width:81px; height:22px;" value="Submit">
```

What we'll need to do next is put some javascript into your form page's HTML that hides the textbox(es) you choose.

for example:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#Submit').click(function(){ //when submit button is clicked
        $("#txt_32").hide(); //hide this element
        $("#txt_33").hide(); //hide this element
        //etc... hide the text boxes by grabbing them with their ID tag
    });
});  
</script>
```

After that, you'll probably want to unhide them. I'm not sure what the end goal is or what you're trying to do, but to get hidden elements to show you call .show() on the elements that we called .hide().